# Strongly typed configuration asp core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to create a strongly typed config section but struggling. Examples show that I can have a POCO and simply have an entry in my json this should automatically resolve.

This is what I have in `ConfigureServices()`. Please note, the `configuration` is `IConfigurationRoot`:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddOptions()
            .AddMvcCore()
            .AddJsonFormatters();

        services.Configure<MySettings>(this.configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));           
    }
```

This is my POCO

```
public class MySettings
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

I get a compiler error `Error:(41, 44) : Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection' to 'System.Action<MySettings>'`.

The JSON config:

```
{
    "MySettings": {
        "Foo": "hello world"
    }
}
```

Clearly, I am doing something silly but unsure what this could be. All sources on the web suggest this "*should"* work.

If further info is required then I can provide that.

Comment: do you have a dependency on Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions in your project.json? you need that, and what will get injected is IOptions<MySettings> then to get MySettings you access the .Value property of IOptions

Comment: Yes I do, I have noticed this however this.configuration.GetSection("").Bind(YOUR OBJECT INSTANCE); could be the missing puzzle

Comment: I'm doing the same as you without .Bind it works for me

Comment: perhaps if you edit your question and show your project.json

Comment: I would leave out the this keyword though that is probably ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
```

in your project.json file.

(The version may be different in your specific case)

Comment: Thank you, that was the missing reference works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

A more complete answer is that you need to add the following nuget package to your ASP Core Project if you want to configure the strongly typed config in that way.

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions
```

The extension methods contained in the package will allow you to configure the strongly typed configuration the way you want to and the way most tutorials show.

```
services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);
```

**Alternatively**, you could add another binder package:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
```

Configuration would then look something like this:

```
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<MyOptions>(x => Configuration.Bind(x));
```

This is the downside of having so many modular packaged up extensions. It gets easy to lose track of where functionality exists.